# How can I see all the functions that belong to 'math.h' in c++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, netbeans, ide

I am learning C++. In Java I could use 'Math.' and then Eclipse would show me all the methods available for the math class. I have tried both Eclipse and Netbeans to find this feature. Control + Space doesn't help with Eclipse or Netbeans (with Eclipse keymap). Documentation in C++ seems less thorough than Java when using an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just look through the header to see the functions that are defined in it. C++ is very well documented, it's just a different set of documentation than you're used to. You'll get used to it.

The first google hit for math.h
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/

And automcomplete, as you're familiar with it is available in Eclipse for C++ and you can turn it on:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/

Comment: How do I use the autocomplete to see the functions, without knowing the name? For example, in java I could do 'Math.' and see every method available. So 'Math.s' would show all the methods available for the math class that start with 's'.

Comment: There is no "math" class. math.h defines (among other things) useful non-member mathematical functions but they're not members of a static class like you might be familiar with. If you want to see what's in math.h you have to go look in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for a GUI answer, but you could just open the header file and read all the virtual function entries?

```
double  sin (double x);
double  cos (double x);
double  tan (double x);
double  sinh (double x);
double  cosh (double x);
double  tanh (double x);
double  asin (double x);
double  acos (double x);
double  atan (double x);
double  atan2 (double y, double x);
...
```

Comment: Where are the virtual functions located? I tried 'control + f3' and I don't see any virtual functions.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know where your math.h header might be located without knowledge of your compiler - on linux you can type `$> locate math.h` and the path to the header will be given (probably along with a load of other paths to similar files). If you're using windows, I imagine there's a similar route to finding headers, but you might just try subdirectories under your compiler install path?